# Android Studio is extremely slow and using a ton of system resources

Tags: android-studio

So I'm pretty sure this question will get closed, but I just want to see if anyone else is experiencing this issue. I'm trying to migrate over to Android Studio, as it just came out of beta and Google announced that they essentially won't be supporting ADT for Eclipse from now on. So far, I'm noticing that the application as a whole is extremely slow and bordering on unresponsive. With every click, I have to deal with extreme latency, which is really making this tool hard to use. After doing a quick check, I've noticed that this one application is using nearly 1GB of memory and I haven't even begun to migrate my project to it! Is anyone else experiencing something like this and does anyone have an idea of what I can do to speed this up? If this doesn't improve then I'll be forced to stop migrating and continue using the Eclipse ADT until something has been done. I'm running Windows 7x64

Comment: Buy more RAM? IDEs generally aren't known for being light-weight.

Comment: How much RAM have you got? Android Studio is unfortunately RAM hungry. I tell people that I recommend a minimum of 8 GB, and more than that to be comfortable.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Wow, amazing idea! 8GB isn't enough eh? Eclipse runs half as much and I don't experience nearly the lag I'm getting with Android Studio.

Comment: With 8GB, you shouldn't be seeing extreme latency in responding to mouse clicks and such. If you see Android Studio running background tasks (updating indices, building, etc.), wait for those to clear. If it's idle and still slow, then do normal computer diagnostics and see if a process is using a lot of CPU, or if it's hitting swap heavily (which indicates lack of RAM), etc. At some point it's really hard to say with confidence what's going wrong because everyone's setup is different.

Comment: With a standard "Hello, World" app loaded, top reports that Android Studio is only using about 6% of my 8GB.  It doesn't seem any slower than Eclipse.

Using more memory does not slow a program down unless it uses so much memory that it causes swapping.  The more stuff a program can keep in memory instead of on disk, the better.

Comment: It's still eating up a ton of RAM (compared to other IDEs), but the application as a whole is working more smoothly after some initial hiccups

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice if the IDE is stuck doing something by looking at bottom right status? 
Make sure you are using bundled Gradle, also Do you have have many dependencies? You might want to check if its getting stuck because it is constantly looking for those dependencies.

Comment: how to check weather we are using bundled Gradle ?,